# Value Error: No back-end

Tags: python, usb, pyusb

trying to use pyusb 1.0 on windows 7 with python 2.7 and libusb 1.2.5

Have installed everything fine, libusb is working as I am getting endpoint information from the test program but when I run this code from the pyusb tutorial -

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import sys

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x20A4, idProduct=0x001)

if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')

dev.set_configuration()

print "WINNING"
```

I am getting a `Value Error: No Backend available error in line 846 of core.py`

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The latest pyusb trunk is supporting libusb 0.x and libusb 1.0. Look like it's not supporting 1.2, and you can see it in the `usb/backend/libusb10.py` in the `get_backend()` method.

Maybe you can use an older version of libusb, or contribute to the 1.0 backend :)